# how can I insert data into table php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a quiz and once the calculation of the grade is finished, I want to add that data to test_attempt table.

Here's its structure.

[image]

Here's the code of the query:

```
<?php

            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vartvald");
            if ($connection->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed:" . $connection->connect_error);
            }

            $user=$_SESSION['user'];
            $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO test_attempts (date, id, mark, top_mark, fk_user, fk_test) VALUES
                ('',null,'$grade','$top_grade','$userid','$fk');";

            var_dump($sql);

            $connection->close();
            ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: explain the error/problem you are facing with your code

Comment: the query doesn't add data to the table

Comment: `date` is empty and $grade, $top_grade, $fk are not defined

Comment: you are inserting in to the date (timestamp) an empty string.

Comment: You are not sending sql stament, you need to prepare (mysqli_prepare), bind (mysqli_stmt_bind_param) and execute (mysqli_stmt_execute).

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus how to insert a timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few mistakes. Your main problem is that you never prepared any query and never executed it. To do it you need to use `prepare()`, `bind_param()`, and `execute()`. Also you are not opening the mysqli connection correctly and your error checking will never work (Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439))

After fixing your errors your code would look something like this:

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "vartvald");
$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO test_attempts (date, id, mark, top_mark, fk_user, fk_test) VALUES(NULL,NULL,?,?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $grade, $top_grade, $userid, $fk);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have not validated whether your SQL is correct in itself, but if you have error reporting switched on, PHP should tell you if you have a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never add data in the database because **you aren't calling any funciton that insert data**:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test_attempts (date, id, mark, top_mark, fk_user, fk_test) VALUES
            ('',null,'$grade','$top_grade','$userid','$fk');";

var_dump($sql);

// missed code to insert data in the database

$connection->close(); // here you close the connection
```

Before closing the connection, call [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
mysqli_query($connection,"$sql");
```

Comment: Don't show them how to fix something they should not use. Show them how to do it with prepared statements.

Comment: it is *your* query is using user inputs without check their contents. which makes your answer quite inconsistent - here you are saying such a code shouldn't be used and here you are promptly writing it as though it's OK

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wrong read `_POST` instead of `_SESSION` in the question, so I deleted the warning from my answer. thanks

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @Dharman I know that escaping is not enough and all data must be checked and "prepared" but in the question I can see only `_SESSION` where it get data, so the user can't change the `_SESSION` contents without accessing the server... Therefore the other variables may be already checked somewhere in his script. So, I didn't preventively suppose that he was in wrong about that.

Comment: @Dharman from my answer code you cannot see that I'm open to SQL Injections only because you don't see **in that code** that I'm not preparing the query. Those variables may be set in the code and previously checked to fit the correct format and content. So, the simple usage of `mysqli_query` does not mean SQL injection.

Comment: It doesn't mean that you should suggest such way. Assume that the data is insecure, because it is a string and it could contain anything. Always use prepared statements when you have variable data. It doesn't matter where it comes from.

Comment: @Dharman I got it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO test_attempts (date, id, mark, top_mark, fk_user, fk_test) VALUES
                (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,null,'$grade','$top_grade','$userid','$fk');";
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following, here you can see that the ***CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*** is passed as first params for `data` and also below the $sql you can see the ***mysqli_query*** which is useed here to execute the insert query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_attempts (date, id, mark, top_mark, fk_user, fk_test) VALUES
                (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,null,'$grade','$top_grade','$userid','$fk');";

mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: this is just for giving an idea what is missing into the question.

Comment: Thank you @NikhilGyan successfully added.